# Animate view's subViews is not working with CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, cagradientlayer

I would like to use CAGradientLayer in my app. I'm inserting a CAGradientLayer at index 0 of the viewController's view's sublayers:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let width = view.frame.size.width
    let height = view.frame.size.height
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 80, width: width/4, height: height/20))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = "label"
    label.alpha = 0
    view.addSubview(label)
    let hideButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
    hideButton.frame = CGRect(x: width/2 - 15, y: label.frame.origin.y + 50, width: width/4, height: 30)
    hideButton.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
    hideButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    hideButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.fadeOutLabel), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(hideButton)

    let gradientButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
    gradientButton.frame = CGRect(x: width/2 - 15, y: hideButton.frame.origin.y + 50, width: width/4, height: 30)
    gradientButton.setTitle("add gradient", for: .normal)
    gradientButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    gradientButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.updateSubviews), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(gradientButton)

}

func updateSubviews() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.label.alpha = 1
        let gradientSublayer = self.makeGradientLayer()
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientSublayer, at: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
}

func makeGradientLayer() -> CAGradientLayer{
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let primaryColor = UIColor.yellow
    let secondaryColor = UIColor.green
    gradientLayer.colors = [primaryColor.cgColor, secondaryColor.cgColor]
    return gradientLayer
}

func fadeOutLabel(){
    print("touch received")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
        self.label.alpha = 0
        }) { (finished) in
            print("animation finished")
    }
}
```

}

However, I have other UI elements on a screen, and they are visible, but when I try to add some animations (animate label's alpha on tapping a button or changing its text), it doesn't work. The button's selector fires, then the animation block executes... but nothing happens. I've tried the most obvious solution - creating a separate view and add it as a subview, but the result won't change. All the subviews on the controller are being added to the main view in the viewDidLoad. Maybe I'm missing something about CALayers?

Comment: I don't see any "animation block". What are you talking about?

Comment: @matt I'm talking about UIView.animate(withDuration: <#T##TimeInterval#>, animations: <#T##() -> Void#>) which is just in another place in code. It fires on tap, but nothing happens to subviews. For example, I'm setting label.alpha to 0 in the animation block, and that line is being executed. But nothing really happens to the label, it's still visible!

Comment: But you need to show the _actual code_ in the _question_. I need to be able to _reproduce_ the problem in order to help fix it. So please show more of your code.

Comment: @matt I've made a sample app and added some code to the question, but it works fine and thus I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: That's excellent! Extremely well done. That is one of my favorite debugging techniques. So now you know that this should work. Use the _differences_ between that and your actual app to figure out what's causing the problem. I bet it turns out to be something totally unrelated you didn't even tell us about it in the question. — By putting your app under version control you can happily start deleting stuff from it until you accidentally remove the cause of the problem. Another great technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original code I was adding labels and other subviews in viewWillLayoutSubviews(). I moved everything to viewDidLoad() and animations started to work. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce that in a sample project. Still not sure were I was wrong.